# CSS 3 / How do I position 3 embedded videos next to each other?

Tags: html, css, video, positioning

My problem is that I don't know how to properly position 3 videos next to each other - for some reason one of them always acts crazy and goes upwards. I tried floating, absolute positioning, now even a table and it still doesn't work!

```css
/* **************************** FONT IMPORTING ******************************* */

@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway');

/* ******************************************* GENERAL STYLING & RESET ******************************************** */

html, body {
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
 color: #FFF;
 background-color: #4b3832;
}


/* ******************************************* NAV BAR STYLING ******************************************** */

.headerInner {
 width: 100%;
 text-align: center;
 background-color: #854442;
 float: left;
}

.headerOuter h2 {
 margin-left: 7%;
 font-size: 200%;
 color: #fff4e6;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 float: left;
}

nav {
 width: 50%;
 float: right;
 padding: 20px;
}

.headerOuter nav ul li {
 list-style: none;
 display: inline;
 float: left;
 margin-right: 5%;
 margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.headerOuter nav ul li a {
 color: #fff4e6;
 font-family: "Raleway", sans-serif;
 text-decoration: none;
}

.headerOuter nav ul li a:hover {
 color: #be9b7b;
}


/* ******************************************* INTRO SECTION STYLING ******************************************** */

.introOuter div {
 margin: 7% 5% 15% 10%;
 width: 40%;
 float: left;
 font-size: 150%;
}

.introOuter div h2 {
 margin-left: 15%;
 color: #ae0001;
}

.introOuter div p {
 margin-bottom: 10%;
}

.introOuter div a {
 padding: 2% 3%;
 text-decoration: none;
 color: #be9b7b;
 margin: 10% 5% 5% 30%;
 border: 2px solid #be9b7b;
}

.introOuter div a:hover {
 color: #ae0001;
 border: 2px solid #ae0001;
}

.introOuter img {
 margin: 5% 15% 10% 0%;
 float: right;
 width: 400px;
 height: 450px;
}


/* ******************************************* THREE COLUMNS SECTION STYLING ******************************************** */

.threeColumns {
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 5% auto;
 background-color: #854442;
}

.oneThird {
 float: left;
 width: 28%;
 font-size: 130%;
 margin-left: 4.5%;
}


/* *************************************** VIDEO GALLERY SECTION STYLING ******************************* */

.videoGallery {
 margin-top: 10%;
 float: left;
 width: 100%;
 background-color: #854442;
}

.videoHeader {
 float: left;
 margin-left: 25%;
 text-align: justify;
 font-size: 150%;
 width: 50%;
}

.videoHeader h2 {
 margin-left: 35%;
}

.table {
 display: table;
}

.row {
 display: table-row;
}

.cell {
 display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
        <title>HHH CORP</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- *************************************** NAV BAR ******************************* -->
        <section class="headerOuter">
            <div class="headerInner">
                <h2>HHH CORP</h2>
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">TOP</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">ABOUT</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">OUR WORK</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">GALLERY</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">CONTACT</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- *************************************** INTRO SECTION ******************************* -->
        <section class="introOuter">
            <div>
                <h2>EXCELLENT WINE</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus. Ut non mi massa. Aliquam fermentum, leo ut sollicitudin porttitor, quam massa cursus ipsum, vitae blandit sapien odio vitae sapien. Vestibulum tincidunt a ligula nec gravida. </p>
                <a href="#">CLICK ME!</a>
            </div>
            <img src="img/wine.png" />
        </section>
        <!-- *************************************** THREE COLUMNS SECTION ******************************* -->
        <section class="threeColumns">
            <div class="oneThird">
                <h2>EXAMPLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oneThird">
                <h2>EXAMPLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim  neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="oneThird">
                <h2>EXAMPLE HEADING</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus.</p>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- *************************************** VIDEO GALLERY SECTION *******************************  -->
        <section class="videoGallery">
            <div class="videoHeader">
                <h2>OUR WORK</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="table">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="cell">
                        <iframe width="320" height="215"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k"></iframe>
                        <h2>A HEADER</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <iframe width="320" height="215"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
                        </iframe>
                        <h2>A HEADER</h2>
                    </div>
                    <div class="cell">
                        <iframe width="320" height="215"
                            src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/XGSy3_Czz8k">
                        </iframe>
                        <h2>A HEADER</h2>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- *************************************** GRID SECTION ******************************* -->
        <section class="theGrid">
            <div class=grid1>
                <img src="#">
            </div>
            <div class="grid2">
                <h2>OUR WORK</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean maximus, nisl sed ornare pellentesque, urna nulla dignissim neque, a fermentum ligula ligula vestibulum risus.</p>
            </div>
            <div class="grid3">
                <img src="#"> 
            </div>
            <div class="grid4">
                <img src="#"> 
            </div>
            <div class="grid5">
                <img src="#"> 
            </div>
            <div class="grid6">
                <img src="#"> 
            </div>
            <div class="grid7">
                <img src="#"> 
            </div>
        </section>
        <!-- *************************************** CONTACT SECTION ******************************* -->
        <div class="contact">
            <h2>CONTACT US</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-youtube"></i></a></li>
                <li><a href="#" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <!-- *************************************** COPYRIGHT SECTION ******************************* -->
        <footer>
            <p> &copy 2017 HHH CORP</p>
        </footer>
        -->
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Responsive web design:

Copy index.htm:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Video</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
                <div class="grid_6">
                    <p>Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum Lorem ipsum 
                </div>          
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <div>
                    <iframe width="" height="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s-Zm_pKIH5w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <div>
                    <iframe width="" height="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s-Zm_pKIH5w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="grid_2">
                    <div>
                    <iframe width="" height="" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/s-Zm_pKIH5w" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                    </div>
                </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Copy style.css:

```
body {
  font-family: 'Nunito', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 1em;
  color: #faf3bc;
  background-color: #0976B2;
}

.grid_1 { width: 15.625%; } /* 125px/800px = 15.625% */
.grid_2 { width: 32.5%; } /* 260px/800px = 32.5% */
.grid_3 { width: 49.375%; } /* 395px/800px = 49.375% */
.grid_4 { width: 65.625%; } /* 525px/800px = 65.625% */
.grid_5 { width: 83.125%; } /* 665px/800px = 83.125% */
.grid_6 { width: 100%; } /* 800px/800px = 100% */

.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  float: left;
}

.container{
  clear:both;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 800px;
  padding: 0% 0;
  margin: auto;
}
img {
  max-width: 100%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 2.750em;
  line-height: 1.25em;
  font-weight: 100;
  letter-spacing: -2.75px;
  color: #ffffff;
}

a:link {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}      /* unvisited link */
a:visited {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* visited link */
a:hover {color:#faf3bc; text-decoration:underline;}  /* mouse over link */
a:active {color:#b4c34f; text-decoration:none;}  /* selected link */

a.selected {color:#ffffff;}  /* selected link */

ul {
  list-style-type:none;
}

.form-input {
  height: 30px;
}
   @media screen and (max-width : 705px) {
.grid_1,
.grid_2,
.grid_3,
.grid_4,
.grid_5,
.grid_6 {
  width: 100%;
}}
```

Comment: I see, it seems to work, but how does one go about positioning the videos left/right. I'm asking since now they are way far off to the left of the screen and I want to center them under the text. I tried margin-left instead of right but it makes them go into two rows.

Comment: Try responsive web design, copy HTML and CSS what I just edits.

Answer (score 0):

I think you forgot `vertical-align` for `.cell`

Try this

```
 .cell {
    vertical-align: top;
 }
```